# Can't get the debugger working in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

So I have been working on a project C# project in Visual Studio Code, and need to make use of the debugging feature.  However, when I run the debugger, I get the following message:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (clrdbg) with Visual Studio
Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software to help you develop and
test your applications.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.1' was not found.

  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:

      C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App

  - The following versions are installed:

      1.1.0

  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.1'.

The program 'c:\Projects\App1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\App1.dll' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
```

My original understanding of the message was that I needed to change the project.json dependency file so that the line showing the version of Microsoft.NETCore.App was updated from 1.0.1 to 1.1.0.  However, this didn't appear to make any difference.  I've tried googling this message, but didn't really understand much of the discussion.  Can anybody point me in the right direction for this one?

If there is any more information I could supply that would be of assistance, please let me know.

At present, my project.json looks like this:

```
{
"version": "1.1.0-*",
"buildOptions": {
"debugType": "portable",
"emitEntryPoint": true
},
"testRunner": "xunit",
"dependencies": {
"xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
"dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
},
 "frameworks": {
 "netcoreapp1.1": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      //"type": "platform", //remove this line if trying to build a native app via runtime section
      "version": "1.1.0"
    }

  },
  "imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
},
"runtimes": { //this section allows you to specify runtime for native build output, note these will not generate unless type:"platform" is commented out in dependancies
    "win10-x64": {},
    "osx.10.11-x64": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your app is expecting a 1.0.1 version of .NET Core, and you are actually running on a 1.1.0 version. I guess that you made a project in Visual Studio 2015, and then try to debug it in Visual Studio Code ?

If so, change the version in project.json to 1.1.0, dotnet restore, build and run again.

Visual Studio 2015 uses a Toolkit with version 1.0.1, while the .NET Core CLI is 1.1.0, so update your project dependencies to 1.1.0 & restore

Comment: That would be possible, it was someone else that built up the project template and I believe they use Visual Studio.  Sorry for being dense, but what bit of the dependencies should be changed?  I tried changing the version number under frameworks > dependencies > Microsoft.NETCore.App and then restored the project, and I'm still getting the same message.

Comment: @jamessct check the project.json file. There should be a couple of references to the .NET Core version.

Comment: @jamessct it is also possible that there is a global.json file where there is a "sdk" version, that also could be changed.

Comment: @jamessct in the project.json, change the version under dependencies > Microsoft.NETCore.App, frameworks > netcoreapp 1.0 -> 1.1.

Comment: I have added my project.json to the OP with the changes I have made.  I have also searched for "NETCore.APP" in the project.lock.json and changed all of the references to 1.1.0, did `dotnet restore`, but to no avail - still getting the exact same message.  Can you see anything I might have missed?

Comment: @jamessct the project.lock , delete it. Change .net core app in dependencies, and also in framework cjange from netcoreapp1.0 to 1.1. That should do it.