# Visual Studio Code isn't allowing me to debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have a .NET Core Web Application that I'm working on. I hit a wall so I'm trying to figure out what's wrong. I clicked the debug button. It begins to run then it stops while outputting the following error message to the Debug Console:

> You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
>   Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
>   to help you develop and test your applications.

That's all it says. Nothing else. It's odd because I'm using VS Code and I haven't had this problem before.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be happening?

Comment: That's a generic header, not an actual error. [Check this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490597/cant-get-the-debugger-working-in-visual-studio-code) and [this issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2029). Is there nothing else? Is the application running and waiting for a client perhaps? Stopped at a breakpoint? Anything logged? Have you trying step-by-step execution?

Comment: It's not waiting for anything. It just stops itself. I added breakpoints to the `startup.cs` and neither of them are hit. When I do `dotnet watch run`, the application works just fine.